# Compilation warning for entitlements with XCode 5 with target Simulator

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios-simulator, warnings

Ever since I have moved to XCode 5 and have applied all the recommended project settings, I have started getting the below compilation warning when building the project for Simulator. Any clue how to get rid of this.

```
Capabilities that require entitlements from "./Resources/Entitlements.plist" may not function in the Simulator
```

[image: Warning message]

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this issue when trying to setup a project on another computer. I had the certificates installed, but not the private key used for the certificates (developer and distribution certs). Once I copied over the private keys used to sign the certificates from the other computer, the warnings went away.

You can see which private key is used for the signing certificate in the Keychain Access app. There should be a drop-down icon under the certificate, indicating which key is associated with that certificate. If you don't see one, you will either need to copy it from another computer (as in my case) or regenerate it and generate a new certificate.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this error setting up a project on a new computer. Ended up having to regenerate the certificates in the dev center and re-loading them in Xcode 5.